# design decision for inventory system

Tags: database, oop, database-design, architecture, inventory

That's my class diagram at the moment:

[image]

I believe I can control the level of stock at each venue by the difference between the quantity of purchased ingredient and the quantity of beverage sold (as each beverage is composed by ingredient).

However, I have a requirement that should allow users to transfer ingredients between venues, and I am wondering what is the best approach for that...

A new purchase order would add the product to one venue's inventory, but how can I remove it from the other one?

Comment: Can a purchase order have lines with negative quantities?

Comment: yes, it is a possibility. I thought about that solution before, but I don't feel it right... I think I should have it separated from the `PurchaseOrder`, in order to track who transferred the stock, but I might be worrying in vain.

Comment: The ERP program which I use has a 'warehouse transfer' table; each line credits one warehouse (apparently 'venue' in your diagram) and debits another. Thus one can perform internal transfers.

Comment: *"I believe I can control the level of stock at each venue by the difference between the quantity of purchased ingredient and the quantity of beverage sold..."* Strictly speaking, that's possible, but it's unlikely. There are *lots* of ways for inventory to go "missing" that have nothing to do with sales. If you track inventory by the difference between purchases and sales, you have an uncomfortable choice when there's a discrepancy: you have to make the db lie either about sales or lie about purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone get to this question, here goes my solution:

I decided to create a table `transfer_stocks` to register all the transfers between venues. This table is also used to solve any discrepancy when stock is counted (when `recipient_id` is nil, it means wastage or stock missing in the venue -`sender_id`).

The products in stock is calculated by de difference between purchases, sales and stock transferred.

My class diagram:

[image]